# Map NSDictionary to JSON array

Tags: ios, json

I have to post data to a server. One of its fields is like this:

`{"pec_email":""1"", "email"":"" }`

I have seen that it is sent as:

```
fields:"{"pec_email":""1"", "email":""}"
```

and when I try to send this field the WebService (made with php) cannot decode that field as JSON array. It handles it as a string. Maybe because of  quotes at the end and the start?
The code I use to store a  `NSMutableDictionary` (`data`) into a JSON array in the DB is:

```
 NSError* error;
 NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:&error];

 if (jsonData )
 {
     NSString* JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes]
                                                     length:[jsonData length]
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     [temp setObject:JSONString forKey:@"fields"];     
 }
```

I also have a RestKit mapping:

```
requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SynchObj class]];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDict];
```

The object mapped has a property

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fields;
```

If I am correct in supposing that the decoding of the JSON string fails because of the formatting, how can send the JSON string as a JSON object?

Comment: Why are you sending it as fields:"{"pec_email":""1"", "email":""}" ?

Comment: I don't see anything related to RestKit in your question. And the data you say you're sending isn't valid JSON. Check what you're actually sending to the server. And show how you're sending the request to the server.

Comment: In fact, as I said the problem is in the formatting...and I cited Restkit because, maybe, some restkit guru can help in doing what I want to do by using restkit'methods...

Comment: If you try to use RestKit and then ask a question about things you don't understand or got wrong then it's a RestKit question. As it is, you need to check what is being sent and show valid JSON for what you want.

Comment: If you're using RestKit then you would not be using JSONString (NSJSONSerialization). You should be using the mapping and an object manager (with request + response descriptors).

Comment: I have to serialize, because the number of data of fields is not known and and I do not know how to create a mapping to such an object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is you're assigning a string value to the key "fields". Your JSON gets serialized as a string, and is treated as a single string value. Instead, try making the value an `NSDictionary`. Assuming that `temp` is a dictionary, your code could look like this:

```
temp[@"fields"] = @{ @"pec_email" : @"1", 
                     @"email"     : @"" };
```

Comment: And then? How to map that to JSON array? Mapping does the job?